# Cannot get Social Media Share Buttons to Line Up in inline list

Tags: html, css, social-media

For the life of me I cannot get these social media share buttons to line-up with my inline list. I nearly had it with a `vertical-align: top;` on the `<li>` but Chrome didn't like that.

Page can be seen here: http://206.72.114.49/sharelinkstest.htm

Full HTML/CSS below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .share-links {
            margin: 8px 0 0 0;
            padding-left: 0;
            display: inline;
        }
        .share-links li {
            margin-left: 0;
            padding-right: 15px;
            list-style: none;
            display: inline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="share-links">
    <li><a title="Post to Google Buzz" class="google-buzz-button" href="http://www.google.com/buzz/post" data-button-style="small-count" data-url="$fqUrl$post.Url"#if ($macros.IsNotNull($post.ResolvedImageUrl)) data-imageurl="$fqUrl$post.ResolvedImageUrl"#end></a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/buzz/api/button.js"></script></li>
    <li><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="$fqUrl$post.Url" data-text="$post.Title by $post.User.ProperName" data-count="horizontal" data-via="lifeorganically">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></li>
    <li><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=$fqUrl$post.Url&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=80;&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=25" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:80px; height:25px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I too was using an inline list for the longest time for social sharing buttons, but I found better results switching to divs, even then I never got it perfect on all browsers, but in the end I didn't give a... on my personal home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the height of the Facebook `iframe` to 20px seems to do the trick.